# doctrine query bulder jsonb result not decoded to an array

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-query

I have a Postgres table like

```
CREATE TABLE catalog.products (
  id UUID primary key,
  name TEXT,
  tags jsonb[] NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
  updated_at timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

where each tag is json like `{"id":"some id", "name":"some name"}`, so if in table `tags` stored like this:

```
{"{\"id\": \"fbe5aead-3870-428d-b744-5ffd907be5a8\", \"label\": \"Against\"}","{\"id\": \"fbe5aead-3870-428d-b744-5ffd907be5a8\", \"label\": \"Against\"}","{\"id\": \"fbe5aead-3870-428d-b744-5ffd907be5a8\", \"label\": \"Against\"}"}
```

and later if I'm trying to get products

```
$productsData =  $this->connection
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('catalog.products')
            ->select('*')
            ->setFirstResult($from)
            ->setMaxResults($to)
            ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
            ->executeQuery()
            ->fetchAllAssociative();
```

`tags` returned as a string and can't be decoded because format is invalid json

```
{"{\"id\": \"fbe5aead-3870-428d-b744-5ffd907be5a8\", \"label\": \"Against\"}","{\"id\": \"fbe5aead-3870-428d-b744-5ffd907be5a8\", \"label\": \"Against\"}","{\"id\": \"fbe5aead-3870-428d-b744-5ffd907be5a8\", \"label\": \"Against\"}"}
```

Comment: of course, I can write some helper function to parse it myself, but I thought Doctrine could do it. I know that ORM  when you have entities able to convert it, but I do not want to use ORM here,